# Stokes' theorem - calculating a flow round $\Delta S$

Tags: vector-analysis

> Let $F(x,y,z) = (y,0,0)$ and $$S = \{ (x,y,z);\,\,{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = 1,\,\,z \ge 0\} $$ Let $\widehat N$ be the unit normal field
>   to $S$ pointing away from the origin. Calculate 
>   $$\iint\limits_S {{\text{Curl }}F \cdot \widehat N}\,dS$$

**My solution:**

Let $$G = {\text{Curl }}F = \nabla  \times F = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  i&j&k \\ 
  {\frac{d}{{dx}}}&{\frac{d}{{dy}}}&{\frac{d}{{dz}}} \\ 
  y&0&0 
\end{array}} \right| =  - k$$
$$\iint\limits_S {{\text{Curl }}F \cdot \widehat N}\,dS = \iint\limits_S {G \cdot \widehat N}\,dS$$

$$\widehat N = \frac{{(2x)i + (2y)j + (2z)k}}{{\sqrt {4{x^2} + 4{y^2} + 4{z^2}} }} = (x,y,z)$$

Projecting the $dS$ element onto $xy$ plane:

$$dx\,dy = dS\left| {\widehat N \cdot \overrightarrow k } \right| = \left| {(x,y,z) \cdot (0,0,1)} \right| = z\,dS \Leftrightarrow dS = \frac{1}{z}\,dx\,dy$$

$$G \cdot \widehat N\,dS = (0,0, - 1) \cdot (x,y,z)\,\frac{1}{z} =  - 1$$
$$\iint\limits_S {{\text{Curl }}F \cdot \widehat N}\,dS =  - 1 \cdot \iint\limits_{{x^2} + {y^2} \le 1} {dx\,dy} =  - \pi $$

Am i correct that the answer should be $ - \pi $ and not $ + \pi $?

Comment: Please correct your definition of $S$, as it stands, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Its exactly the same way the professor gave this problem, so i wont correct anything all i need to know if its + pi or minus pi.

Comment: Are you sure? How do you interpret the equation (inequality?) $$x^2+y^2+>z^2=1$$ This just doesn't make any sense, maybe you should correct this after all. Also, what is $$\int\int> A\cdot B \;dS$$ supposed to represent?

Comment: There is no inequality, the symbol was incorrectly parsed, i have fixed it.